# How to return the Class of a generic type

Tags: java, vert.x

I have this compilation problem:

[image]

Here is the class in question:

```
package huru.entity;

import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import java.util.Date;

public class BaseEntity <T extends BaseModel> extends JsonObject {

  private T model;

  public BaseEntity(T m){
    this.model = m;
  }

  public void setUpdateInfo(String user){
    this.model.updatedBy = user;
    this.model.updatedAt = new Date();
  }

  public JsonObject toJsonObject(){
    return JsonObject.mapFrom(this.model);
  }

  public T getEntityType (){
    return this.model.getClass();  // doesn't compile
  }

}
```

I also tried using

```
 public T getEntityType (){
    return T;  // doesn't compile
 }
```

but that clearly doesn't work either. Anybody know how I can return the class instance of that generic type?

I also tried this:

```
  public Class<T> getEntityType (){
    return this.model.getClass();
  }
```

and I get:

[image]

and then I tried this:

```
  public Class<? extends T> getEntityType (){
    return this.model.getClass();
  }
```

and I have:

[image]

Comment: I need to return the class of the model, not the model instance...the last attempt I have seems the closest, but not quite right.

Comment: Try here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following code. I think it works.

```
 public Class<? extends BaseModel> getEntityType (){
    return model.getClass();  
 }
```

Comment: yeah that worked, I wonder why. `T` should work, maybe it's a shortcoming of the language.

Comment: I think it has something to do with Type Erasure. The information about the type is not available at runtime.

Answer (score 6):

You appear to be confused. You're returning the class that represents T, not a T.

Let's replace T with String and show why what you're doing makes no sense:

```
private String model;

public String getEntityType() {
    return model.getClass();
    // Of course this does not work; model.getClass() is not a string!
}

public String getEntityType() {
    return String;
    // This doesn't even compile.
}
```

To try to explain, this:

```
public T getEntityType() {
    ....
}
```

requires you to return an actual instance of whatever T is. Not whatever type T is representing. Just like 'String' means you should return an actual instance of String, not the concept of String, the type.

Perhaps you meant to do this:

```
public T getEntityType() {
    return model;
}
```

or more likely, given that you named this method 'getEntityType', what you mean is this:

```
public Class<? extends T> getEntityType() {
    return model.getClass();
}
```

Yes, `? extends T`, because model is a T, or any subtype of T.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo<T> {
final Class<T> typeParameterClass;

public Foo(Class<T> typeParameterClass) {
    this.typeParameterClass = typeParameterClass;
}

public void bar() {
    // you can access the typeParameterClass here and do whatever you like
 }

}
```

Comment: Add some explanation along with your code. Code only answers are not much useful.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that getClass is defined in Object to give you a `Class< ? >` with a wildcard as the generic parameter. If you want to return `Class< ? extends T >` you will need to cast to that:

```
return (Class< ? extends T >) (model.getClass());
```